# Only Connect Unchained

Tags: word, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be partitioned into 4 groups of 4 connected words.
Additionally, each of the four groups can be represented by a single group-word.
Finally, the four group-words are connected by a single five-letter word.

```
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
    |     SEA      |     SKY      |     DOWN     |    UNDER     |  
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
    |    CROSS     |     EYES     |    SCREEN    |    MYTH      |  
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
    |    DRIVE     |     HOME     |    BRONCO    |    TYPE      |  
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
    |    BOOM      |     GANG     |     QUA      |    BLOCK     |
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**Can you identify the four groups and the associated group-words?**
**What is the five letter word that links the group-words together?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This wall can be resolved into the following four groups (with explanations for some of the less immediately obvious ones):

> *Group 1: **BUSTER***
>
>  - [Bronco BUSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broncobuster) - one who breaks wild horses to the saddle (alternatively, a [wrestling move](https://prowrestling.fandom.com/wiki/Bronco_Buster)!);
>  - [MythBUSTER](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/myth-buster) - a person/book, etc. that sets out to prove something commonly believed to be true actually is not;
>  - [GangBUSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gangbusters) - a law-enforcement officer who breaks up criminal gangs;
>  - BlockBUSTER - a hit movie (for example) that enjoys huge commercial success.
>
>  *Group 2: **WRITER***
>
>  - ScreenWRITER - a person who writes a screenplay;
>  - UnderWRITER - a person or company that undertakes to finance or otherwise support or guarantee something;
>  - TypeWRITER;
>  - [SkyWRITER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skywrite) - one who writes messages in the sky using smoke emitted from an aeroplane.
>
>  *Group 3: **TOWN***
>
>  - HomeTOWN;
>  - DownTOWN;
>  - [BoomTOWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boomtown) - a community that undergoes sudden, rapid development and growth;
>  - [CrossTOWN](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crosstown) - situated at opposite sides of town.
>
>  *Group 4: **TRAIN***
>
>  - [QuaTRAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatrain) - a four-line stanza in poetry;
>  - EyesTRAIN - fatigue of the eyes;
>  - [SeaTRAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seatrain) - a band and shipping company;
>  - [DriveTRAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drivetrain) - part of a vehicle.

Furthermore, these four groups can be linked by the word:

> **GHOST**
>
>  - GhostBUSTER - [Who ya gonna call?!](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087332/)
>  - GhostWRITER - a person who writes a book or piece of writing on someone else's behalf;
>  - Ghost TOWN - deserted settlement;
>  - Ghost TRAIN - fairground ride.

This answer would link to the title too, since:

> Ghosts are often depicted with clanking CHAINS, and the song 'UNCHAINED Melody' featured in the Patrick Swayze film, *Ghost*...

Comment: Just barely beat me to posting the answer - nice! I got stuck on "touch" for too long...

Comment: @Deusovi We do have a very slightly different answer though - SEA and CROSS in different groups!

Comment: Huh, so we do! Interesting - I was pretty confident in CROSS, but not sure at all about SEA. I like yours better, but Google confirmed that SEA in the position I had it *was* a thing.

Comment: @Deusovi It was QUA that stuck me for ages. I was going down the Latin route for far too long!

Comment: For the first word you have in group 1, I think [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broncobuster) is the intended explanation instead.

Comment: @Deusovi Oh, cool, thanks - it was a new phrase to me, to be honest - don't get many broncos over 'this side of the pond'!

Comment: Nice work. My original intention with cross/sea was what you've written but both answers here are great.

Answer (score 6):

The groups are:

> Group 1: **QUA**TRAIN, **EYES**TRAIN, **CROSS**TRAIN, **DRIVE**TRAIN
>  Group 2: **BRONCO**BUSTER, **BLOCK**BUSTER, **GANG**BUSTER, **MYTH**BUSTER
>  Group 3: **UNDER**WRITER, **TYPE**WRITER, **SCREEN**WRITER, **SKY**WRITER
>  Group 4: **BOOM** TOWN, **HOME**TOWN, **DOWN**TOWN, **SEA** TOWN

And their commonality is

> the words that can be placed to succeed them: TRAIN, BUSTER, WRITER, TOWN. These can all be preceded by **GHOST**.

Comment: My original intention with cross/sea was what Stiv wrote but this answer is also great (I just hadn't noticed the opportunity to switch them).